# trying to connect to Azure from my Java code for test automation and run data factory pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, automation-testing

We are in process to try and create Java based test automation

1. The build will be in Azure DevOps
2. Will run a Data Factory Pipeline
3. Check Status

I am looking for help with being able to Connect to Azure (options so as to achieve CI)

Please help suggest, preferably with some Snipets.

Answer (score 0):

To establish connection to Azure data factory, add below package to your Product

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure.resourcemanager</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-resourcemanager-datafactory</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-beta.16</version>
</dependency>
```

Azure Active Directory token authentication depends on correct configuration of following environment variables.

•   AZURE_CLIENT_ID for Azure client ID.

•   AZURE_TENANT_ID for Azure tenant ID.

•   AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET or AZURE_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE_PATH for client secret or client certificate.

You can follow the Java code given below to create Data Factory resource.

```
// container
final String containerName = "adf";
storageManager.blobContainers().defineContainer(containerName)
    .withExistingStorageAccount(resourceGroup, STORAGE_ACCOUNT)
    .withPublicAccess(PublicAccess.NONE)
    .create();

// blob as input
BlobClient blobClient = new BlobClientBuilder()
    .connectionString(connectionString)
    .containerName(containerName)
    .blobName("input/data.txt")
    .buildClient();
blobClient.upload(BinaryData.fromString("data"));

// data factory
Factory dataFactory = manager.factories().define(DATA_FACTORY)
    .withRegion(REGION)
    .withExistingResourceGroup(resourceGroup)
    .create();


// pipeline
PipelineResource pipeline = manager.pipelines().define("CopyBlobPipeline")
    .withExistingFactory(resourceGroup, DATA_FACTORY)
    .withActivities(Collections.singletonList(new CopyActivity()
        .withName("CopyBlob")
        .withSource(new BlobSource())
        .withSink(new BlobSink())
        .withInputs(Collections.singletonList(new DatasetReference().withReferenceName(inputDatasetName)))
        .withOutputs(Collections.singletonList(new DatasetReference().withReferenceName(outputDatasetName)))))
    .create();

// run pipeline
CreateRunResponse createRun = pipeline.createRun();

// wait for completion
PipelineRun pipelineRun = manager.pipelineRuns().get(resourceGroup, DATA_FACTORY, createRun.runId());
String runStatus = pipelineRun.status();
while ("InProgress".equals(runStatus)) {
    sleepIfRunningAgainstService(10 * 1000);    // wait 10 seconds
    pipelineRun = manager.pipelineRuns().get(resourceGroup, DATA_FACTORY, createRun.runId());
    runStatus = pipelineRun.status();
}
```

For more information follow this [documentation](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/java/azure-resourcemanager-datafactory/1.0.0-beta.16/index.html)